# How to fetch image of the screen from video memory?

Tags: image, memory, video, screen, fetch

Which library may I use to do it? You can think of it as getting the screenshot.

Note: I'm talking about PC. I don't specify OS since I hope that the library is supposed to do it in a cross-platform way. If that's not possible then I will be fine with the Windows only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Java, class `java.awt.Robot`, method `createScreenCapture(Rectangle screenRect)`